# How could we specify 'windowSoftInputMode' only for specific views on React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

How could we specify '***windowSoftInputMode***' only for specific views for Android app built on React Native?

I'm running into this issue where I need to use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

for most of my app but then I need to use the opposite for a specific library **react-native-gifted-chat**.

Would it be possible to set the value of ***windowSoftInputMode*** and then override it on specific views?

Comment: There may be a better way, but it nothing else you could do it by using a custom component.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Got the same problem

Comment: @Erased The only solution I could find is this native module - https://github.com/zubricky/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust. I've tested and it works just great.